# DIV HEIGHT and WIDTH full page centering not working

Tags: html, css

#### Background:

I'm trying to visualize the structure for my future pages and containers in the full screen.

#### Current JSFiddle:

[Available here](http://jsfiddle.net/uz2behax/).

```html
<div class="top">top</div>
<div class="middleleft">left</div>
<div class="center">center</div>
<div class="middleright">right</div>
<div class="bottom">bottom</div>
```

```css
.top
{
background-color: yellow;
height: 20%;
}

.middleleft
{
float: left;
    background-color: blue;
width: 20%;
}

.center
{
float: left;
        background-color: white;
width: 60%;
margin: auto;
height: 60%;
}

.middleright
{
float:left;
    background-color: red;
width: 20%;
}

.bottom
{
height: 20%;
background-color: green;
}
```

#### Problem:

For some reason, even with height defined on the CSS, it does not fill the entire screen to the bottom, linking only enough background color height and width until the text ends.

#### Need:

What code change is needed to fill the screen to the dimensions it has (like the 60% width on the center div), without having to write characters to the bottom to fill out the div on the screen?

#### Code type restrictions:

I do not wish to use JavaScript or JQuery in the solution, only CSS and HTML.

Many Thanks

Comment: `html,body{height:100%}`

Comment: thx, I will vote you up as soon as I am allowed, you were to first to answer (though not in answe form) :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**JSFIDDLE CODE**](http://jsfiddle.net/uz2behax/6/)

I added this:

```
html, body {height:100%;}
```

Then I set your center div to height 100% (and made it pink so it can be seen more easily).

**EDIT:** I left your side divs alone as I'm not sure what you want to do with those, but I hope this helps.

Comment: Darn candlejack, I was just about to post an-

Comment: thanks for the tips. the purpose and intent is to force the %% on any screen and scale with different resolutions. doesnt my structure achieve that? does it further edit?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean, @AlbanLusitanae. If you look at either mine or Mary Melody's JSFiddle examples and resize the output windows, you can see how the layout behaves at different screen sizes. Both of our examples will maintain a 100% height of the window - is this what you were looking for?

Comment: Absolutely my point, and I thank you for that. I was just wondering if the code does function cross-platform (also including mobiles due to mobile browser versions, as user319940 warned about below).

Comment: sorry one thing: the center was height 100% but I need to add that to the left and right since the purpose is to force a "full screen" parameter from the start with the bottom as a footer kinda reference. Then if it scales, I can place whatever I want in there and the structure scales in any platform :)

Comment: I now have have achieved the code I wanted, [on this JSF](http://jsfiddle.net/uz2behax/6/). Is there anyway to make this better or shorter, or this is how short as it gets (I suppose I can make duplicate entries apply to more than on class...)

Comment: I can't see anything in the fiddles that would cause any major problems for a specific mobile browser. It works fine on my android, for example. My interpretation of the mobile-related answer below is that while your markup structure may *work*, it won't necessarily make sense on all browsers - it depends entirely on what sort of content you want to put on the final site, hence the suggestion to add some graphics or text content to see what happens. There's a lot of advice out there on designing content for mobile and 'mobile-first' web design, but that's a different question to the original.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the top/center/bottom content into one class allowing the left/right divs to merely sit outside of the wrapper.

Comment: does this scale in different resolutions? i want absolute control over each div, as less surprises as possible

Comment: Yes it does. It should achieve what you want.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved, but I think you need to ask yourself *why* you want to do this. Today, with mobile there is no standard screen size, so a full screen for one screen is not going to be a full screen for another.

Instead, why not try adding some real content to your proposed structure and see how it stacks up then?

Or, if it's purely for mockup purposes, then maybe use some graphics software where it's much easier and quicker to move things around.

Comment: thanks for the tips. the purpose and intent is to force the %% on any screen and scale with different resolutions. doesnt my structure achieve that? does it further edit?

Comment: Are you planning on having left and right side bars even on mobile screens?

Comment: The bars might be transparent and everything; won't be much of a problem to content specifically since the front pages will give way to more text structured htmls instead of div locked ones. However, I want to test it as such and how it is now (the concept testing of scale with resolution) to see what they look like in mobile browsers, both those who wrap text and don't, to carefully weight my choices for the future